# A form with 3 radio buttons and 2 Submit buttons to redirect to URL's

Tags: php, forms, redirect, radio-button

I am creating a simple form in Joomla. I will create an article page with the form and save the script in the template. A user will need to click on a radio button that will redirect to a different URL or page:

---

O  Choice 1
O  Choice 2
O  Choice 3

[Submit button 1]  [Submit button 2]

---

If user selects Choice 1 and Submits button 1, it will redirect to page1.php
If user selects Choice 2 and 3 and Submits button 1, it will redirect to page2.php
If user selects Choice 1 and Submits button 2, it will redirect to page3.php
If user selects Choice 2 and 3 and Submits button 2, it will redirect to page4.php

I really appreciate some help on this. Thanks.

Comment: Are you wanting to redirect from the server side or client side?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect directly, you'll need JavaScript to change the link the submit button refers to when the user clicks an option.

If not, I would recommend that you create a new PHP-File redirect.php, refer to it and then check inside this file which option the user has chosen and redirect him to the asociated page. To redirect with PHP you need to change the header, so you mustn't display any HTML content in the redirect.php file, just the PHP code.